# How can I output the list of positions of the cells with specific text in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the postions of the cells which have "Pi".

My dataframe is as follows. As you can see, the cells with "Pi" are in `0,2`, `1,1`, `1,3` in format `column,row`.

```
   Pi Column_B
0   F   Kitten
1   L    Pippy
2  Pi     Lamb
3   K    Pikjh
4   K     Momo
```

Therefore, the output that I want is `[(0,2),(1,1),(1,3)]`. My code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
# My dataframe
data = {'Column_A':['F','L','K','K','K'],
      'Column_B':['Kitten','Pippy','Lamb','Pikjh','Momo']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Search for the cell which includes "Pi"
search_for_Pi = df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('Pi').any(), axis=1)
Found_Pi_Position = pd.DataFrame(search_for_Pi)

# Print the position of the cells which include "Pi"
Print_Pi_Position = list(Found_Pi_Position[Found_Pi_Position == True].index)
print(Print_Pi_Position)
```

However, I got the output `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. Please help me finding the error.

Comment: This is just silly hard to do! I've been trying to solve it, and I have to wonder why this functionality doesn't just already exist. Find where elements are in a data frame should not be hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
    df
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .set_axis(range(df.shape[1]), axis=1)
    .apply(lambda s: s[s.str.contains('Pi')].index.values)
    .to_frame()
    .apply(lambda s: [(s.name, i) for i in s.values[0]], axis=1)
    .explode()
    .tolist()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand you want to filter out and located the strings that contain the PI, key string and check out what indexes have it. And put it into a list?

For that a simple loc
And a index class selections will help you out

```
pi_rows = df.loc[df.Pi.str.contains('Pi')]

pi_rows_index =  df.loc[df.Column_b.str.contains('Pi') | df.Pi.str.contains('Pi')].index
```

If you want to stack the returned object in a list, without having the index type

```
[str(i) for i in pi_rows_index]
```

Will return the wanted list

Comment: Thank for your answer. However, this way can only output the index in the first column "Pi". I want to output the postions of all columns at once. Is there other way to make it?

Comment: Ah so you want to apply to you entire df? Well not gonna lie to you that is not very optimal usually, you just select the series you know will have  such value to apply to your entire df, is asking for a very slow selective process. Lemme show you in my answer

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. Because the dataframes I am going to analyze are very irregular, sometimes the column names are not in the first row, and somethings the column names are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=[]
def function1(s:pd.Series):
    for k,v in s.to_dict().items():
        if 'Pi' in v:
            list1.append((s.name,k))

df1.T.reset_index(drop=True).T.apply(function1)
list1
```